# MPMoviePlayerController in Swift

Tags: swift, mpmovieplayercontroller, ios8

I have this code but it doesn't show anything only a black frame.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    var filepath: NSString = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Akbar_ipad", ofType: "mp4")
    var fileURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: filepath)
    let moviePlayerController = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: fileURL)

    moviePlayerController.shouldAutoplay = true
    moviePlayerController.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceType.File


    moviePlayerController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 200, y: 200, width: 500, height: 300)



    self.view.addSubview(moviePlayerController.view)

    moviePlayerController.prepareToPlay()
    moviePlayerController.play()

    ...
```

Have you got any idea how can i solve my problem? I am going crazy!

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a similar problem:  [How to load MPMoviePlayerController contentUrl asynchronous when loading view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25117568/how-to-load-mpmovieplayercontroller-contenturl-asynchronous-when-loading-view)

But here some ideas for you:

1. Maybe the url is constructed incorrectly/not local. Try using: `let fileURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Akbar_ipad", withExtension: "mp4")`
2. You might need a global variable to hold a reference to the movie player instance (as described in the documentation.

Comment: I don't understand why NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource didn't work while NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource did. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

For your problem, you maybe forgot add your resources as "Bundle Resources"
Follow below step to add:

1. In the Project Navigator select your project root
2. Select "Build Phases" tab
3. In "Bundle Resources" section to click "+" to add your resources

After that I think you can use both `URLForResource` and `pathForResource`