# How to load MPMoviePlayerController contentUrl asynchronous when loading view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, mpmovieplayercontroller

I try to play a video using a MPMoviePlayerController. The setup is: I push a new ViewController, then set up the view and the movie player instance in viewDidLoad and then use a NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL() where I load the REST resource for the movie to give me the URL. In the completion block I set the contentUrl of the movie player instance to this url and say play. However, the movie frame stays black. If I set the contentUrl hardcoded to the url either in viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear, or viewDidAppear, the movie shows just fine.
The errorLog and accessLog are both nil.
So I assume something is wrong with the asynchronous url loading and assigning of the movie contentUrl.

Setup: Swift, Xcode 6 beta, iOS 8.

Below some code snippets:

```
class PresentationsViewController {

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
        let presentationViewController = PresentationViewController(presentations[indexPath.row])
        navigationController.pushViewController(presentationViewController, animated: true)
    }

}

class PresentationViewController {

    var presentation: Presentation?
    var moviePlayer: MPMoviePlayerController?

    convenience init(_ presentation: Presentation) {
        self.init()
        self.presentation = presentation
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController()
        moviePlayer!.view.frame = CGRect(x: X, y: Y, width: W, height: H)
        moviePlayer!.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceType.Unknown
        moviePlayer!.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.Embedded

        NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(presentation.url) { data, response, error in
            // Some JSON parsing etc.

            self.moviePlayer!.contentURL = presentation.videoUrl
            self.moviePlayer!.prepareToPlay()
            self.moviePlayer!.play()
        }.resume()

        view.addSubview(moviePlayer.view)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this was a bug in the Swift betas or iOS 8 betas, but changing the code to use AVPlayer worked.

```
import AVFoundation
import AVKit

let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()

// In async block:

if let player = AVPlayer.playerWithURL(url) as? AVPlayer {
    playerViewController.player = player
}
```